concurrent kafka client offset commit management data structure
Question: Comparing Ring Buffer with Hash Map and Interval Designs for Kafka Client - Which is Better?
I'm working on optimizing a Kafka client for high-throughput message processing. We're considering two different designs for managing message offsets and statuses: a ring buffer with a hash map and an interval-based approach. I'm seeking insights on their performance and whether granular locking is possible for each design in Go and Python.
Design 1: Ring Buffer with Hash Map

Structure: Uses a ring buffer to store message offsets and a hash map to quickly update their processing status.
Operations:

Add Offset: O(1) - Append the offset to the buffer.
Update Status: O(1) - Use the hash map to quickly locate the offset in the buffer and update its status.
Forward Scan: O(n) - Sequentially scan the buffer to find the next commit point.



Design 2: Interval-Based Approach

Structure: Stores intervals of processed message offsets (e.g., [offset1, offset5]) instead of individual offsets.
Description: In the interval approach, instead of updating the status of individual offsets, we manage and merge intervals. When an offset is processed, it either extends an existing interval or starts a new one. The key operations are adding offsets, updating statuses within intervals, and merging intervals when necessary.
Operations:

Add Offset: O(1) - Insert the offset into the appropriate interval.
Update Status: O(1) - Update the status within the interval.
Interval Merge: O(1) - Merge intervals when a message is processed.
Forward Scan: O(1) - Directly access the highest initial offset without scanning.



Performance Comparison:

Ring Buffer with Hash Map:

Add Offset: O(1)
Update Status: O(1)
Forward Scan: O(n)


Interval-Based Approach:

Add Offset: O(1)
Update Status: O(1)
Interval Merge: O(1)
Forward Scan: O(1)



Questions:

Which design is better for high-throughput message processing?
Is granular locking feasible for both designs, particularly for the interval-based approach?

How can granular locking be implemented in Go, considering its concurrency model?
How effective is granular locking in Python, given the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)?



Any insights, examples, or experiences with these designs would be greatly appreciated!

The interval approach is just a bunch of nodes with foward and backward pointers. Start with a dummy head node and tail node. Each pending offset is [offset, null]. On completion of offset 3, change [3, null] to [3, 3]. Ending being not null represents finished range. Then absorb previous is previous is done and not dummy. Absorb next also. You are done. No need to worry about allocation or out of bound like the ring buffer. On commit, read the first interval, if end is still null, noop. Otherwise that's the offset to commit if changed.

I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve here. The client allows you to actually get the committed offsets. Since this only has to be done during startup, local accounting seems to be a bit of an overkill.

I'm also confused: Your main problem is managing message status quickly, not message processing? This seems to indicate that your messages are too small.

@markus-w-mahlberg Do you mean that the confluent kafka client will automatically manage the offsets? So there is no need to do local accounting even if I process the messages out of order using multiple threads?

@JackPeng I give you one better: It is done serverside per consumer group: https://dattell.com/data-architecture-blog/understanding-kafka-consumer-offset/

Detail: you either need to enable auto-commit or commit messages manually. auto.offset.reset is only used when there is no offset information available for that particular consumer group.

I ended up going with the interval approach. It makes debugging more efficient since monitoring status is just a matter of printing out the first interval.

The actual parallel processing could have been done with hashing to multiple queues, especially if ordering within some particular (topic, partition, key) is needed. However, I opted to create an adapter over the producer so that a simple thread pool can process messages with different keys concurrently. The adapter has 2 levels of queuing. The first level is a dictionary where each key gets a queue. The second level queue only has messages that are ready to dispatch, ie, no message with same key is still being processed or already in this queue, to guarantee ordering.

There is also a set of keys that are being processed, to guarantee ordering. I use a producer full and a consumer empty condition variable over a re-entrant lock to manage the atomicity and consistency of the adapter.

This works well for python's IO-bound use cases. Can easy monkey patch threads into green threads to allow thousands of threads running in the same process without other code change.
